# Issue while building a nativescript app with iOS 12.1 SDK

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have built my android and iOS app with NativeScript. For Android everything was good... But when I tried to publish the app for iOS I got this error from Apple Store connect:

`SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 11.3 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.`

So the app was rejected... So, I changed the Deployment target in NativeScript SideKick app in de Properties -> iOS -> Deployment Target to 12.1

But then when I run `tns run ios`

I get:

```
clang: error: invalid iOS deployment version '-mios-simulator-version-min=12.1', iOS 10 is the maximum deployment target for 32-bit targets [-Winvalid-ios-deployment-target]
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
** BUILD FAILED **
```

My computer is 64b as it's and MacBook Pro i5 with macOS Mojave

So I don't know which is the issue.. Could you please help me?

Comment: Looks like you've included a 32-bit target.

Comment: @IanMacDonald where is that? how can I change it?

Comment: What's the version of NativeScript runtime you are using in your project?

Comment: @Manoj the versions is (I run tns --version) 5.0.1

Comment: The runtime version is the one specified in your `package.json` as `tns-ios`. What you are referring to is the CLI version.

Comment: Ups.. sorry! @Manoj so the version is "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }

Comment: @IanMacDonald could you please help me to know how I can found out which target is 32.bit? or how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same issue... Please check the answer I get from [GitHub](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4197) from NickIliev

Open the file from your local NativeScript CLI installation e.g. (example path on Mac)

```
open /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services
```

Inside the services folder locate and open the `ios-project-service.js`

Modify the VALID_ARCHS and ARCHS for device and simulator builds so that `arm7` and `i386` are removed

for device builds remove `arm7`

```
 const defaultArchitectures = [
    'ARCHS=arm64', , // remove arm7 here
    'VALID_ARCHS=arm64' , // remove arm7 here
];
```

For simulator builds remove `i386`

```
return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    args = args
        .concat([
        "build",
        "-configuration", buildConfig.release ? "Release" : "Debug",
        "-sdk", "iphonesimulator",
        "ARCHS=x86_64", // remove i386 here
        "VALID_ARCHS=x86_64", , // remove i386 here
         "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO",
         "CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=" + path.join(projectRoot, "build", "emulator"),
         "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=",
])
```